# mex file is crashing, how to use MATLAB_MEM_MGR in matlab?

Tags: c++, matlab, debugging, crash, mex

I have compiled a c++ code to MEX-file, but on calling this MEX-file, it crashes.
It gives the following error message in MATLAB:

> Segmentation violation detected

I tried using try-catch in C++ file to print the message in the catch block
like,

```
try {
    //my code;
}
catch(std::exception &e)
{
    mexPrintf(e.what());
    mexEvalString("drawnow;");
    return;
}
```

but the print message does not work and the code still crashes.

On looking at Google, most of the time it points to some form of message given by MathWorks: http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/25900

which instructs to set a environment variable `"MATLAB_MEM_MGR=debug"`,
but it does not explain how to use it? Can anyone please explain it?

Answer (score 4):

First off, try/catch will not catch a segmentation violation. It only catches C++ exceptions, not signals like sigsegv.

Second, to "use" `MATLAB_MEM_MGR`:

1. Set the environment variable `MATLAB_MEM_MGR` to "debug" in an OS shell (like a Command prompt on Windows or a terminal on Unix),
2. Run MATLAB from that same shell,
3. Run your MEX-function normally from that MATLAB.

As [Q3.5](http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#Why_is_my_MEX_file_crashing.3F) of the FAQ says, if the MEX-function corrupts memory by (for example) writing past the end of a MATLAB-allocated block of memory, MATLAB will report the corruption when the block of memory is freed.

You may instead want to try running your MEX-function under a debugger. [This tech note](http://web.archive.org/web/20120413212003/http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1600/1605.html#gen_debugging) has several links describing how to do so on various platforms.

**EDIT**: previous link is dead, here is the latest [doc page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/debugging-c-c-language-mex-files.html).

Comment: Hi, I could fix the problem. I was getting crash because of wrong format of input, the wrong format was causing devide by zero.

Comment: Before posting this message I had tried to debug code with cpp, however I could not catch it. As i mentioned, I tried using try catch, printing etc. nothing helped me. Moreover, I never thought that the crash can be due to devide by zero, so all my effort was to see if i am trying to access extra memory. Anyways thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `mexEvalString("drawnow;")`. It took me 5 hours to figure out this.